# Computing a covariance matrix and seeing NA values from cov() in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following price data:

```
treas <- read.csv(file = 'treas.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

2YR     3YR     5YR     7YR     10YR    30YR
0.41    0.85    1.65    2.18    2.6     3.43
0.41    0.85    1.65    2.2     2.61    3.45
0.4     0.82    1.63    2.17    2.59    3.44
0.41    0.86    1.66    2.19    2.6     3.44
0.43    0.88    1.69    2.22    2.62    3.45
0.45    0.93    1.71    2.24    2.64    3.47
0.44    0.91    1.7     2.23    2.65    3.47
0.42    0.88    1.66    2.17    2.58    3.41
0.45    0.93    1.7     2.21    2.6     3.41
0.49    0.95    1.71    2.21    2.61    3.4
0.51    0.99    1.77    2.27    2.66    3.44
0.48    0.95    1.71    2.21    2.61    3.43
0.48    0.94    1.71    2.22    2.64    3.47
0.5     0.94    1.71    2.22    2.63    3.44
0.48    0.96    1.72    2.23    2.63    3.45
0.49    0.95    1.7     2.19    2.59    3.41
0.48    0.92    1.68    2.17    2.57    3.38
0.46    0.9     1.64    2.14    2.53    3.35
0.45    0.88    1.64    2.14    2.54    3.36
0.47    0.88    1.62    2.13    2.53    3.34
0.47    0.9     1.66    2.17    2.58    3.4
0.49    0.95    1.71    2.22    2.64    3.46
0.52    0.98    1.74    2.25    2.65    3.47
0.52    1       1.74    2.24    2.63    3.44
0.51    0.99    1.7     2.19    2.58    3.38
0.51    0.97    1.68    2.17    2.57    3.37
0.46    0.93    1.66    2.15    2.55    3.38
0.48    0.92    1.65    2.13    2.53    3.34
0.48    0.95    1.68    2.17    2.55    3.36
```

I use the `apply()` function to traverse all of the columns and calculate the daily returns using the `Delt()` function in the Quantmod package.

```
apply(treas, 2, Delt)
```

This gives us:

```
> treas_ret
                X2YR         X3YR         X5YR         X7YR        X10YR        X30YR
   [1,]           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
   [2,]  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.009174312  0.003846154  0.005830904
   [3,] -0.024390244 -0.035294118 -0.012121212 -0.013636364 -0.007662835 -0.002898551
   [4,]  0.025000000  0.048780488  0.018404908  0.009216590  0.003861004  0.000000000
   [5,]  0.048780488  0.023255814  0.018072289  0.013698630  0.007692308  0.002906977
   [6,]  0.046511628  0.056818182  0.011834320  0.009009009  0.007633588  0.005797101
   [7,] -0.022222222 -0.021505376 -0.005847953 -0.004464286  0.003787879  0.000000000
   [8,] -0.045454545 -0.032967033 -0.023529412 -0.026905830 -0.026415094 -0.017291066
   [9,]  0.071428571  0.056818182  0.024096386  0.018433180  0.007751938  0.000000000
  [10,]  0.088888889  0.021505376  0.005882353  0.000000000  0.003846154 -0.002932551
  [11,]  0.040816327  0.042105263  0.035087719  0.027149321  0.019157088  0.011764706
  [12,] -0.058823529 -0.040404040 -0.033898305 -0.026431718 -0.018796992 -0.002906977
  [13,]  0.000000000 -0.010526316  0.000000000  0.004524887  0.011494253  0.011661808
  [14,]  0.041666667  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000 -0.003787879 -0.008645533
  [15,] -0.040000000  0.021276596  0.005847953  0.004504505  0.000000000  0.002906977
  [16,]  0.020833333 -0.010416667 -0.011627907 -0.017937220 -0.015209125 -0.011594203
  [17,] -0.020408163 -0.031578947 -0.011764706 -0.009132420 -0.007722008 -0.008797654
  [18,] -0.041666667 -0.021739130 -0.023809524 -0.013824885 -0.015564202 -0.008875740
  [19,] -0.021739130 -0.022222222  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.003952569  0.002985075
  [20,]  0.044444444  0.000000000 -0.012195122 -0.004672897 -0.003937008 -0.005952381
  [21,]  0.000000000  0.022727273  0.024691358  0.018779343  0.019762846  0.017964072
  [22,]  0.042553191  0.055555556  0.030120482  0.023041475  0.023255814  0.017647059
  [23,]  0.061224490  0.031578947  0.017543860  0.013513514  0.003787879  0.002890173
  [24,]  0.000000000  0.020408163  0.000000000 -0.004444444 -0.007547170 -0.008645533
  [25,] -0.019230769 -0.010000000 -0.022988506 -0.022321429 -0.019011407 -0.017441860
  [26,]  0.000000000 -0.020202020 -0.011764706 -0.009132420 -0.003875969 -0.002958580
  [27,] -0.098039216 -0.041237113 -0.011904762 -0.009216590 -0.007782101  0.002967359
  [28,]  0.043478261 -0.010752688 -0.006024096 -0.009302326 -0.007843137 -0.011834320
  [29,]  0.000000000  0.032608696  0.018181818  0.018779343  0.007905138  0.005988024
```

Lastly, I pass the newly-created `treas_ret` data frame to the `cov()` function.

Unfortunately, we get:

```
      X2YR X3YR X5YR X7YR X10YR X30YR
X2YR    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
X3YR    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
X5YR    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
X7YR    NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
X10YR   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
X30YR   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
```

`str(treas_ret)` gives us:

```
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "X2YR" "X3YR" "X5YR" "X7YR" ...
```

I tried to pass `treas_ret` to the `as.numeric` function, but that didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to ensure that the daily returns are numeric before being passed to the cov() function?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell `cov()` what to do with the `NA` values:  `cov(apply(treas_ret, 2, Delt), use = "complete.obs")`.

Comment: `treas_ret` is already numeric, it is due to presence of `NA`s you are getting all NA from `cov`. Either remove them or use `use = "complete.obs"` as suggested by @H1

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks all.

Comment: @H1 you should write an answer or do you think this has already been asked before?

Answer (score 0):

`treas_ret` is already a numeric matrix. It is due to presence of `NA`s in the matrix you get all the values as `NA` when you are using `cov`.

You can remove `NA`s and then use `cov`

```
library(quantmod)
treas_ret <- apply(treas, 2, function(x) na.omit(Delt(x)))
cov(treas_ret)


#               X2YR         X3YR         X5YR         X7YR        X10YR         X30YR
#X2YR  0.00189071490 0.0009671260 0.0004751261 0.0003592459 0.0002632325 0.00006466673
#X3YR  0.00096712596 0.0009824173 0.0004852795 0.0003843313 0.0002665753 0.00014473384
#X5YR  0.00047512612 0.0004852795 0.0003163515 0.0002553111 0.0001938068 0.00011919805
#X7YR  0.00035924594 0.0003843313 0.0002553111 0.0002219907 0.0001694694 0.00011048543
#X10YR 0.00026323252 0.0002665753 0.0001938068 0.0001694694 0.0001472908 0.00010040032
#X30YR 0.00006466673 0.0001447338 0.0001191980 0.0001104854 0.0001004003 0.00008497829
```

Another option is to use `use = "complete.obs"` as suggested by @H1 which gives the same result.

```
treas_ret <- apply(treas, 2, Delt)
cov(treas_ret, use = "complete.obs")
```